# Free options of dynamic Gantt chart plugin for JIRA

Tags: automation, charts, plug-in, jira

I am looking for a free plugin for a Gantt chart in JIRA. I searched a lot but it seems that most of them are non-free.

I am not sure if there exist such kind of plugin that can implement dynamic visualization, that is, it can automatically update the chart when the data pulled from JIRA is changed.